# Qt - Strange access violation while adding a row in QTableWidget

Tags: visual-studio, qt, gridview, access-violation, qtablewidget

I'm completely newbie with Qt, but I need to determine if I can use this IDE to create professional projects. For that reason, I created a demo project using Visual Studio 2019, and the provided Qt Designer to design my user interface.

My demo contains a grid view I created using a QTableWidget object, configured with 7 columns in the designer, and in which I can add and remove cells dynamically, by clicking on (+) and (-) buttons.

Here is the code to add and remove a cell:

```
void MainForm::OnAddClicked()
{
    const int row    = (m_CellCount / 7);
    const int column = (m_CellCount % 7);

    // add a new line if required
    m_UI.twGridView->setRowCount(row + 1);

    QString                 text;
    QFont                   font("Segoe UI", 14);
    QFontMetrics            metrics(font);
    std::unique_ptr<QLabel> pImage(new QLabel());

    switch (m_CellCount % 3)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            text = metrics.elidedText("This is a very very long device name", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/Device.png) center center;");
            break;
        }

        case 1:
            text = metrics.elidedText("iPod Shuffle Robbie", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/Shuffle.png) center center;");
            break;

        case 2:
            text = metrics.elidedText("iPad Robbie", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/iPad.png) center center;");
            break;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<QLabel> pLabel(new QLabel(text));
    pLabel->setFixedHeight(20);
    pLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignBottom);
    pLabel->setFont(font);
    pLabel->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(243, 243, 243);");

    std::unique_ptr<QWidget>     pWidget(new QWidget());
    std::unique_ptr<QVBoxLayout> pLayout(new QVBoxLayout(pWidget.get()));
    pLayout->addSpacing(10);
    pLayout->addWidget(pImage.get());
    pLayout->addSpacing(10);
    pLayout->addWidget(pLabel.get());
    pWidget->setLayout(pLayout.get());
    pWidget->setStyleSheet("background: none;");
    pImage.release();
    pLabel.release();
    pLayout.release();

    m_UI.twGridView->setCellWidget(row, column, pWidget.get());
    pWidget.release();

    ++m_CellCount;
}

void MainForm::OnDelClicked()
{
    if (m_CellCount)
    {
        --m_CellCount;

        const int row    = (m_CellCount / 7);
        const int column = (m_CellCount % 7);

        delete m_UI.twGridView->cellWidget(row, column);
        m_UI.twGridView->setRowCount(!column ? row : row + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_UI.twGridView->rowCount())
            delete m_UI.twGridView->cellWidget(0, 0);

        m_UI.twGridView->setRowCount(0);
    }
}
```

This code works globally well, and do the job. However, for a reason I cannot figure out, I get sometimes strange access violations while the below line is executed:

```
// add a new line if required
m_UI.twGridView->setRowCount(row + 1);
```

For example, if I add 9 cells to show a 2nd row, then I remove 3 cells to delete the previously created 2nd row, and then I add 2 cells again, I get an access violation on the above mentioned line, while the 2nd row is added again.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It could be the `delete` statements, `QTableWidget` [takes ownership of the data](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget) you set with `setCellWidget` so you don't need (or rather are not allowed to) to do any deleting yourself, resizing the table itself is enough to make Qt do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adversus said above, deleting the cell wasn't a great idea. Replacing the delete lines by:

```cpp
m_UI.twGridView->setCellWidget(row, column, NULL);
```

resolved the issue for me.

Here is the corrected code:

```cpp
void MainForm::OnAddClicked()
{
    const int row    = (m_CellCount / 7);
    const int column = (m_CellCount % 7);

    // add a new line if required
    m_UI.twGridView->setRowCount(row + 1);

    QString                 text;
    QFont                   font("Segoe UI", 14);
    QFontMetrics            metrics(font);
    std::unique_ptr<QLabel> pImage(new QLabel());

    switch (m_CellCount % 3)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            text = metrics.elidedText("This is a very very long device name", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/Device.png) center center;");
            break;
        }

        case 1:
            text = metrics.elidedText("iPod Shuffle Robbie", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/Shuffle.png) center center;");
            break;

        case 2:
            text = metrics.elidedText("iPad Robbie", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/iPad.png) center center;");
            break;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<QLabel> pLabel(new QLabel(text));
    pLabel->setFixedHeight(20);
    pLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignBottom);
    pLabel->setFont(font);
    pLabel->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(243, 243, 243);");

    std::unique_ptr<QWidget>     pWidget(new QWidget());
    std::unique_ptr<QVBoxLayout> pLayout(new QVBoxLayout(pWidget.get()));
    pLayout->addSpacing(10);
    pLayout->addWidget(pImage.get());
    pLayout->addSpacing(10);
    pLayout->addWidget(pLabel.get());
    pWidget->setLayout(pLayout.get());
    pWidget->setStyleSheet("background: none;");
    pImage.release();
    pLabel.release();
    pLayout.release();

    m_UI.twGridView->setCellWidget(row, column, pWidget.get());
    pWidget.release();

    ++m_CellCount;
}

void MainForm::OnDelClicked()
{
    if (m_CellCount)
    {
        --m_CellCount;

        const int row    = (m_CellCount / 7);
        const int column = (m_CellCount % 7);

        //delete m_UI.twGridView->cellWidget(row, column);
        m_UI.twGridView->setCellWidget(row, column, NULL);

        m_UI.twGridView->setRowCount(!column ? row : row + 1);
    }
    else
        m_UI.twGridView->clearContents();
}
```

Thank you very much Adversus.